# Use Discrete Fourier Transform to calculate infinite periodic spectrum

Tags: c#, opencv, fft, dft

Using open cv, I am able to gleaning heavily from the example [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/discrete_fourier_transform/discrete_fourier_transform.html). And given the input image here:
[image]

I'm getting the following as an output:
[image]

However, I want to find not just the center spectrum, I want to find the periodic spectrum of the repeating structure. Getting something like this:
[image]

Essentially, I want to use the fourier transformation to find the the orientation and center for each repeating square. Is there a way to accomplish this in opencv? I haven't found any example of this online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the first three steps [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/discrete_fourier_transform/discrete_fourier_transform.html):

```
        Mat padded = new Mat();                            //expand input image to optimal size
        int optimalSizeRows = Cv2.GetOptimalDFTSize(i.Rows);
        int optimalSizeCols = Cv2.GetOptimalDFTSize(i.Cols); // on the border add zero pixels
        Cv2.CopyMakeBorder(i, padded, 0, optimalSizeRows - i.Rows, 0,
            optimalSizeCols - i.Cols, BorderTypes.Constant, Scalar.All(0));

        Mat paddedFloat = new Mat();
        padded.ConvertTo(paddedFloat, MatType.CV_32FC1);
        Mat[] planes = { paddedFloat, Mat.Zeros(padded.Size(), MatType.CV_32F) };
        Mat complexI= new Mat();
        Cv2.Merge(planes, complexI);         // Add to the expanded another plane with zeros
        Mat dftImage = new Mat();
        // Apply fourier transformation
        Cv2.Dft(complexI, dftImage, DftFlags.ComplexOutput);
```

Then do a call MulSpectrums (essentially a coefficent auto correlation) on the dft resulting image, and do an inverse FFT and I get the results I need.

```
        Mat mulSpecMat = new Mat();
        Mat inverse = new Mat();
        Mat norm = new Mat();
        Cv2.MulSpectrums(dftImage, dftImage, mulSpecMat, DftFlags.ComplexOutput, true);
        Cv2.Dft(mulSpecMat, inverse, DftFlags.Inverse | DftFlags.RealOutput);
        Cv2.Normalize(inverse, norm, 0, 255, NormTypes.MinMax);
```